# My Hive query is running for long time

Tags: hive

I ran the below query from hive CLI.
The query is running for long time and failing after that.

```
SET hive.tez.container.size=10240; 
SET hive.tez.java.opts=-Xmx8192m; 
set tez.runtime.io.sort.mb=4096; 
set tez.runtime.unordered.output.buffer.size-mb=1024; 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true; 
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict; 
set hive.vectorized.execution.reduce.enabled; 
set hive.execution.engine=tez;

SELECT 
cust_his.cname AS cname  
,cust_his.creg AS creg 
,Upper(Trim(cust_his.ccountry)) AS ccountry 
,Upper(Trim(cust_his.cloc)) AS cloc
FROM  
customer_history cust_his
WHERE  
cust_his.cust_d BETWEEN 20160501  AND 20160531
AND Substr(Trim(cust_his.cloc), 1, Locate('|', cust_his.cloc, 1) - 1) <> ''
AND Substr(Trim(cust_his.cloc), 1, Locate('|', cust_his.cloc, 1) - 1) IS NOT NULL
AND cast(Trim(cust_his.cmfid) as int) NOT IN ( 1,2,3 )
AND cust_his.cmat = '8';
```

The table is partitioned on cust_d column.
The table is having 420TB of data.

Please help me to resolve this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: What type is cust_d ?

Comment: cust_d is int  data type column and which is daily partitioned.

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Please run `explain dependency select ...` and check if all the partitions are between 20160501  and 20160531

Comment: Have you checked?

Comment: Yes. Its using the partitions from 20160501 and 20160531.

Comment: All the partitions between 20160501 and 20160531

Answer (score 0):

Your query should run on mapper only because there is no group by or join or files merge.

Check how many mappers starts and is partition pruning works, check query plan.
If partition pruning does not work, try to replace `BETWEEN` condition with `>=` and `<=`, sometimes it helps, vectorized execution may not support `BETWEEN` in your version according to this: https://docs.hortonworks.com/HDPDocuments/HDP2/HDP-2.3.0/bk_dataintegration/content/query-vectorization.html.

Also add this:
set hive.vectorized.execution.enabled = true;

Also this condition is redundant:

```
AND Substr(Trim(cust_his.cloc), 1, Locate('|', cust_his.cloc, 1) - 1) IS NOT NULL
```

You do not need it because you already have the same `<> ''`, this automatically excludes `nulls`

Comment: could you please help me how to check how many mappers starts and is partition pruning works (or) not .And how to  check query plan

Comment: And the exception text will help a lot

Comment: It looks like cust_d is not date at all... Check it IS PARTITION PRUNING WORKS, what explain plan says about partitions and SIZE, NUM ROWS, check it with and without WHERE clause

Comment: Vectorized execution also does not support any file format except for ORC. I would start with asking the OP some questions.

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz It works with other formats on Hive 1.2.1, I can confirm it works with plain text csv as well

Comment: Out put of explain plan

Comment: @Dudu Markovitz I will check once more tomorrow about vectorizing, may be I was looking on JOIN of CSV and ORC.

Comment: I am unable to add explain plan in the comment please help me

Comment: You can do it yourself. Compare using winmerge or some other tool explain plan with WHERE partition filter and without. Check what it says about partitions and size

Comment: And exception ?

Comment: Plan not optimized by CBO
Stage-0
Fetch Operator
limit:-1
Stage-1
Map 1
File Output Operator [FS_52176]
compressed:false               
Statistics:Num rows: 39675432 Data size: 12565434678 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL
table:{"input format:":"org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat","output format:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat","serde:":"org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe"}
Select Operator [SEL_52175]
outputColumnNames:["_col0","_col1","_col2","_col3"]

Comment: Statistics:Num rows: 39675432 Data size: 12565434678 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL
Filter Operator [FIL_52177]
predicate:((((substr(trim(cloc), 1, (locate('|', cloc, 1) - 1)) <> '') and substr(trim(cloc), 1, (locate('|', cloc, 1) - 1)) is not null) and (not (UDFToInteger(trim(cmfid))) IN (1,2,3))) and (cmat = '8')) (type: boolean)
Statistics:Num rows: 39675432 Data size: 24523585020 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL
TableScan [TS_52173]
alias:his
Statistics:Num rows: 545678990 Data size: 29578435678907 Basic stats: COMPLETE Column stats: PARTIAL --with WHERE

Comment: Error is Halting due to out of memory error. Some times vertex failed

Comment: and where is cust_his.cust_d BETWEEN 20160501  AND 20160531 condition?

Comment: This is not came in  explain plan

Comment: These two are different pieces of plan.

Comment: This plan is with cust_his.cust_d BETWEEN 20160501 AND 20160531 condition.Since I was not able to paste at a time in comment window I have pasted part by part

Comment: I do not see partition prunning  nor vectorizing in it

Comment: Why it's not using partition purnning (or) vectorization.Could you please provide me the solution.

Comment: I can help, but please provide create table statement and data example so i will be able to reproduce it, also please provide exception message for better understanding